# Why do Filenames created under UTF-8 not match the UTF-Codepage layout?

Tags: filename, utf-8, character-set, file-sorting

According to Wikipedia's [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) [Codepage Layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout), its [character-set](/questions/tagged/character-set) is as follows:

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0-9 : ; < = > ? @ A-Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a-z { | } ~
```

But (excepting `/`), filenames beginning with these character are sorted by name differently:

```
! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ 0-9 $ a A z Z
```

Why is this? Does it have to do with the file system? File Manager? Locale? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The sort order is controlled by the LC_COLLATE category of the locale settings. It doesn't depend on the character encoding.

Note that some programs, especially command line programs, may not use the locale settings for sorting.